# Can I use e.parameter in conjunction with a global variable to retrieve an external variable in Google Apps Scripts?

Tags: variables, parameters, namespaces, google-apps-script, global

I realize the question is confusing.  I'm trying to reference many widgets that were created in the main loop of my script from a secondary function using e.parameter.

Instead of referencing each e.parameter separately, by its name, I'd like to be able to make one reference to e.parameter and have the parameter name portion be a globally defined variable.

As in:

```
e.parameter.some_id
```

Would be the same as:

```
var test=[]
test[0]='some_id'
e.parameter.(test[0])
```

Or some other syntax.  I'm trying to reference the parameters in a loop, and using the array means I can increment a for loop counter instead doing if tests for each parameter individually.

I'm certain there's an easier way to do this, but I'm still new to java.

Answer (score 1):

Use `e.parameter[test[0]]` . It is not java but JavaScript

Comment: Thank you again Waqar - I haven't had a chance to accurately test this yet, but I will. :)